# 403 Forbidden due to Client Denied by Server Configuration

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm in the final stages of launching a Django webapp, and I have been stumped for days trying to understand why I keep getting a 403 Forbidden error (You don't have permission to access / on this server). When I check my error log, the last portion the output is as follows:

```
[Fri Sep 11 04:54:04.525052 2015] [:error] [pid 31126:tid 140413402863360] [client 104.156.102.54:62884] ImportError: No module named foodshop.settings
[Fri Sep 11 05:10:08.926570 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31122:tid 140413615802240] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Sep 11 05:10:09.912491 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31345:tid 139760551360384] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 11 05:10:09.912511 2015] [core:notice] [pid 31345:tid 139760551360384] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2' 
[Fri Sep 11 05:10:15.259159 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 31349:tid 139760274188032] [client 104.156.102.54:63064] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/foodshop
[Fri Sep 11 05:15:00.604266 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31345:tid 139760551360384] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Sep 11 05:15:01.657535 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31455:tid 140370721130368] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 11 05:15:01.657552 2015] [core:notice] [pid 31455:tid 140370721130368] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Sep 11 05:15:06.215273 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 31458:tid 140370621613824] [client 104.156.102.54:63126] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/foodshop
[Fri Sep 11 05:15:07.389851 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 31458:tid 140370613221120] [client 104.156.102.54:63126] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/foodshop
[Fri Sep 11 05:15:08.519875 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 31458:tid 140370427979520] [client 104.156.102.54:63126] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/foodshop
[Fri Sep 11 05:33:55.993127 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31455:tid 140370721130368] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Sep 11 05:33:56.047551 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31598:tid 140492520712064] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 11 05:33:56.047572 2015] [core:notice] [pid 31598:tid 140492520712064] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Sep 11 05:34:01.575422 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 31602:tid 140492306102016] [client 104.156.102.54:63348] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/foodshop
[Fri Sep 11 05:34:02.481030 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 31602:tid 140492297709312] [client 104.156.102.54:63348] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/foodshop
[Fri Sep 11 05:34:03.342911 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 31602:tid 140492289316608] [client 104.156.102.54:63348] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/foodshop
```

A few things to note...the application runs perfectly on my localhost. Also, I ran *sudo chown -R www-data apache2.conf* to change the ownership to apache. I'm more than happy to share the entire error log if it will be more useful, but it is very long.

I'm running this on an EC2 instance (Ubuntu 14.04).

You can see my 000-default.conf file below as well:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/gather/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/gather/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/gather/src/foodshop>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess gather processes=2 threads=15
    WSGIProcessGroup gather
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/gather/src/foodshop/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your apache2.conf file make sure it looks something like that:

```
<Directory /path/to/project/>
        WSGIProcessGroup name
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

instead of like that (which is config for apache 2.2, while above is for apache 2.4)

```
<Directory /path/to/project/>
        WSGIProcessGroup name
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**EDIT**

Try changing your apache config to this (not sure what is your root of the app, you might need to add change one line to: `<Directory /home/ubuntu/gather/src/foodshop/>`:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

WSGIDaemonProcess gather processes=2 threads=15
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/gather/src/foodshop/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/ubuntu/gather/src/>
    WSGIProcessGroup gather
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /home/ubuntu/gather/src/foodshop/media/
<Directory /home/ubuntu/gather/src/foodshop/media/>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/gather/src/foodshop/static/
<Directory /home/ubuntu/gather/src/foodshop/static/>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: How do I find the name of the WSGIProcessGroup?

Comment: `name` is up to you, it has to be the same though as in `WSGIDaemonProcess`, ex: `WSGIDaemonProcess name processes=2 threads=15`

Comment: @acs254 Do you want me to post you a full example apache config? Or maybe better, post yours and I can tell you whats wrong.

Comment: @acs254 made some changes to the answer, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for posting the edits. I tried them out, and now I get a 500 Internal Sever Error (which seems like a step in the right direction). Now I'm getting the following errors:

[Mon Sep 14 02:39:59.616496 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4623] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined....

and the same for ${APACHE_PID_FILE}, ${APACHE_RUN_USER}, ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}, and ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}

I think I can figure out how to define them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @acs254, cool, let me know if you need other help. Don't forget to accept the answer once you get it going.